# I need to delete the last 7 characters of a specific range of cells that are already selected

Tags: vba, selection

I'm trying to remove the last 7 characters, which are gibberish in a report I run, but only for the cells I have selected in the spreadsheet. I keep on getting a Run-Time Error 13 though.

```
Sub Mitts()

With Selection
    .Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 7)

End With
End Sub
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! `For Each i in ActiveWorksheet.Selection (New line) i.Value = Left(i.Value, Len(i.Value) - 7) (New line) Next i` -- Replace "(new line") with new lines ;-)

Comment: Where do i add that in exactly?

Comment: this goes between the `Sub` and `End Sub` lines. Remove the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one cell in the Selection range, `.Value` returns an array, not a single value.  Best way to approach this is to loop through all the cells in the Selection:

```
Sub Mitts()

    Dim target As Range
    For Each target In Selection
        With target
            If Len(.Value) > 7 Then
                .Value = Left$(.Value, Len(.Value) - 7)
            End If
        End With
    Next target

End Sub
```

Note that you should also be testing the length before you try to truncate it to avoid the 'Invalid procedure call or argument' exceptions you'll get on empty cells or cells without enough text to truncate.